# Mathematics sign for ceil and floor functions

Tags: calculus, functions, soft-question

What is mathematics sign for ceil and floor ?

Comment: Do a google search for floor and ceiling functions.

Comment: It is the ceiling function.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceiling_function

Comment: As @Christopher says, it’s the *ceiling* function, written $\lceil x\rceil$.

Comment: Thanks @BrianM.Scott, I couldn't remember how to format it, so I just linked it to what it actually was.

Comment: @user2982390 : Try this! http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Answer (score 3):

Most would recognize this as the "ceiling function" (as opposed to the 'floor' function, which is rounding a number down instead).

It's written `\lceil x \rceil` : $\lceil x \rceil$

(For that matter, floor is written `\lfloor x \rfloor`: $\lfloor x \rfloor$ )

Comment: So when I write I write [5/2] eg. for both floor and ceil ?

Comment: @user2982390 $[x]$ is a notation for floor funciton found in many older books (eg, Sierpinksi). Nowadays floor is $\lfloor x \rfloor$ with the lines on the top of the bracket removed to emphasize you're rounding *down*. Similarly $\lceil x \rceil$ means rounding up.

Comment: No, look at the symbols...the notch is there on the floor at the bottom, while the notch is at the top for the ceiling function.

Comment: I see, thanks :)